# Spine.js and select-all checkbox

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I'm trying to make tableView with select-all checkbox on spine.js and coffeescript. I cant understand how i can bind select-all click to select all models in table. "select-all" checkbox is rendered at UserList view.
ItemView code:

```
class UserItem extends Spine.Controller
    className: 'user-item'
    tag: 'tr'

    elements:
        'input[type="checkbox"]': 'checkbox'

    events:
        'click input[type="checkbox"]': 'itemChbClicked'

    constructor: ->
        super
        @item.bind("update",  @render)
        @item.bind("destroy", @remove)

    render: ->
        @html require('views/user/item')(@item)
        @

    remove: =>
        @el.remove()

    itemChbClicked: (e) -> 
        @item.selected = @checkbox.is(':checked')
```

ItemList code:

```
class UserList extends Spine.Controller
    className: 'user-list'

    elements:
        '.items': 'items'
        ".select-all": "select_all_chb"

    constructor: ->
        super

        @html require('views/user/list')()
        User.bind("create", @addOne)
        User.bind("refresh", @addAll)
        User.fetch()


    addOne: (user) =>
        view = new UserItem(item: user)
        @items.append(view.render().el)

    addAll: =>
        User.each(@addOne)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're close.  In UserList create the select_all_chb function and have it change the users:

```
class UserList
  select_all_chb: =>
    User.each (user) ->
      user.selected = true
      user.save()
```

Since you've bound the "change" event to "render", all the checklist items will be redrawn.